# Export Objects in MSAccess Application to Text Objects, and Import Into A New MDB

Tags: ms-access

I need to export all of the objects from my MDB to text files in a folder, and them import those text files as fresh Access objects into a brand new MDB, using some VBA code.

Does anyone have the source code for this?  I know it exists out there somewhere, I just can't find it at the moment.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Corrupt Objects within a Corrupt Microsoft Access MDB](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/corruption/corruptobjects.htm)

The little documented `SaveAsText` and `LoadFromText` may help if an object is corrupted or otherwise behaving weirdly.

At the debug/immediate window type:

> Application.SaveAsText acForm,"MyForm","c:\form.txt"

You can load the file into a new MDB.

> Application.LoadFromText acForm,"MyForm","c:\from.txt"

Sample code at http://www.datastrat.com/Code/DocDatabase.txt for saving all objects in an MDB.

Comment: Works perfectly. A blessing