# MS Access 2013 export query-to-XML not saving file

Tags: ms-access

- I'm trying to save several of my queries as XML files in order to re-assemble my database in another location where the only viable transfer method is text or XML files via email (long story).
- When I use the built-in export function, Access allows me to select a save location and nest the schema inside of the XML file, and then **says that the export was completed successfully. The file is not in the destination folder**, and no error was thrown.
- This only happens when exporting bound queries. Other Access elements (tables and forms, for example) export just fine.
- If I watch the folder during the export process, I see a file appear very briefly, and then dissapear. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: Cannot transfer db in a zip folder attached to email? Cannot replicate issue.

Comment: @June7 No, unfortunately. Trying to transfer between levels of network security and the automated transfer tools don't allow .accdb files (even in .zip). Also can't use removable media.

Comment: Use Process Monitor to find out who kills the xml file. My bet would be on some background process that thinks the file is dangerous.

Comment: Zip the file => rename the zip to .txt => email it over. If the file is too large, use win rar split the zip files by allowed size.

Comment: @Andre I'll give that a shot.

Comment: @krishKM Can't do that with the security protocol comparing the file contents to the file extension. I'm looking to solve an Access issue, not violate my organization's security protocol.

Comment: @SmrtGrunt You are already violating your org's IT policy, hence you are trying to move data in a text form.(which is also getting deleted) You should probably consult your IT team and get it transferred!

Comment: *the XML export works for other Access elements without being deleted, just not queries.* - please add that to the question. -- An alternative might be: `Application.SaveAsText` and `Application.LoadFromText` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088814/export-objects-in-msaccess-application-to-text-objects-and-import-into-a-new-md