# I can no longer import XML files into access using the import tool in access

Tags: xml, ms-access, import

I have imported XML files into Access before many times following the simple instructions of the import XML file, but for some strange reason, it no longer works.

After i choose the file location and i am prompted with the message box (where i choose to import the data and the structure) i click on ok and then, nothing happens !!!! I have waited for a while as well but nothing comes up.
Can someone please help, i have tried it on XML files that were successfully imported before but it no longer works !!

Comment: Hi, welcome!  Can you edit your question and add the particular error message you get?

Comment: @kristianp It sounds like there's no error message generated. Just nothing happening. This sounds like it might be related to my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599216/ms-access-2013-export-query-to-xml-not-saving-file